# sublime text actualvim how to add path to neovim?

Tags: sublimetext3, neovim

I want to try out the actualvim plugin for sublime, but I can't figure out how to add the path to neovim. And the page instruction never explained how to.

Comment: What did you try, and what didn't work? Give the exact code you tried that didn't work. The "Usage" section of the readme has instructions: https://github.com/lunixbochs/ActualVim#usage

Comment: @Justin M. Keyes Haven't added any code since I don't know much of sublime

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted below?

Comment: @Justin M. Keyes Yeah I did, but I could not manage to make it work. I get the error: ImportError: No module named 'ActualVim'

Comment: That's a different problem, and is addressed on the issue tracker: https://github.com/lunixbochs/ActualVim/search?q=ImportError%3A+No+module+named+%27ActualVim%27&type=Issues (It also depends on the full error log, which you need to post here or on the ActualVim issue tracker)

Answer (score 2):

The [readme](https://github.com/lunixbochs/ActualVim/blob/2bb16490939156aa185f26654a0e398da29bb37d/README.md#usage) does not mention the setting name, but [the code](https://github.com/lunixbochs/ActualVim/blob/41330881f56be4c9e97fdf3cafb88cd7bd4cf330/settings.py#L15) reveals a `neovim_path` setting.

In Sublime's menu, go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> ActualVim Settings` and set the `neovim_path` key to the full `nvim` path:

```
"neovim_path": "/path/to/nvim"
```

If you're on Windows, use `/` slashes (not `\`), or you will need to escape the slashes, e.g.:

```
"neovim_path": "C:\\path\\to\\nvim.exe"
```